# Push Notifications in BB10

Tags: android, push-notification, blackberry-10

I'm porting an Android application to BlackBerry10. I have checked out [this](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html) tutorial on the Blackberry Developer site. They are giving only vague information there.

One of my doubts is to whether to do the server registration on GCM or BB Cloud. If BB Cloud, where can I find the code for the same?

Secondly for android, I can receive a notification by using a `GCMIntenetService` and specifying `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` as a receiver. How will this differ for Blackberry implementation?

Any help in the right direction will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to register your app with BB infrastructure in order to receive notifications on blackberry device

[here is link for registartion](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121) and it will take maximum of 6 days for blackberry to respond to your request and they will provide you with you app id and several other related docs as well

Answer (score 3):

you should use GCMBaseIntenetService with GCMRegisterar .
I have successfuly ported Android Push Notification enabled in BB10.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @muhammad, but I'm no longer developing for BB10 :)

Comment: Tell me the process@Muhammad

Comment: Sorry for late reply,let me know on which point you are stuck? Have you registered your application on BlackBerry server?

Comment: @Muhammad, I registered my app on BB server and I got appid, ppgurl etc. I developed Android app using Xamarin. Where exactly I have to put android.cfg file? In some places I was suggested to put in root of Android project and under Assets folder. Before creating apk, I added this file. I generated bar file using apk, but android.cfg file doesn't exist there. What is the issue?

Comment: I hope this [link](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html) would work for you, you have to put android.cfg file on specific location.

Comment: My BB device was getting push notification when I was using test environment credentials, when it was expired I again resubmitted for production environment, I got new credentials, but after updating new credentials, I always getting INVALID_SENDER error while registering with GCM, my project number is valid, not sure why its happening, I have sent mail to BB team regarding this, but no response from them. You have any idea how to fix, u can answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882157/invalid-sender-error-in-android-ported-blackberry-app-after-upgrading-production) also.